# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I really did not understand how the type assignment system works for variables in typescript.
Can anyone help me why this does not work.
Thank you

```
valorParcela:number;
totalCost:number;
VendaProdutoVendaNParcelas: number;

this.valorParcela = Number( this.totalCost / this.VendaProdutoVendaNParcelas).toFixed(2);
```

I expected a simple parseFloat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a `string` which you are assigning to a variable which should be `number`. You need another pair of `()` to convert the result of `toFixed` back to number

```
this.valorParcela = Number(( this.totalCost / this.VendaProdutoVendaNParcelas).toFixed(2));
```

Or you can use the unary `+` trick to perform number conversion:

```
this.valorParcela = +(this.totalCost / this.VendaProdutoVendaNParcelas).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.toFixed(2);
```

Always returns string.

And you have assigned type `number`.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` returns string. throwing an error because trying to assign to the number type. so just cast to `Number(expression)` again or make this variable as string `this.valorParcela`

```
this.valorParcela = Number(Number(this.totalCost / this.VendaProdutoVendaNParcelas).toFixed(2)));
```