# React useState Props: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. TS2322

Tags: typescript, use-state, react-typescript

I am trying pass to Props to React useState Hooks.  Both my props are required and number but I am getting Typescript error that:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2322

But I am not passing anywhere the string. So, I don't know why I am getting this Typescript. I don't want to pass props `any`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface Props {
  strength: number;
  speed: number;
}

const Courseinfo = ({ strength, speed }: Props) => (
  <>
    <div>
      <h1>{strength}</h1>
      <h1>{speed}</h1>
    </div>
  </>
);

const App = () => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState<Props>({ // This Props throws me error 
    strength: 0,
    speed: 0,
  });

  const { strength, speed } = character;
  return (
    <>
      Strength:
      <input
        type="number"
        value={strength}
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          setCharacter({ ...character, strength: e.target.value })
        }
      />
      Speed:
      <input
        type="number"
        value={speed}
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          setCharacter({ ...character, speed: e.target.value })
        }
      />
      <Courseinfo strength={strength} speed={speed} />
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: perhaps you convert the string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394034/type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-number

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown where you show that comment?  Or is it thrown where you call `setCharacter` in the inputs below?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-engelbart-zk9kv?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: @Krisna `input type="number"`'s value is not a number, it is a string

Comment: @RameshReddy Thanks for the answer. I did not know that `input type="number"` is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input type="number"`'s value is a string

Here's the fixed [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cloud-5nu2c).

Changes:

```
interface Props {
  strength: string;
  speed: string;
}
```

and event's type can be

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
```

Alternately you can also convert `event.target.value` to a number(`+event.target.number`) instead of changing the prop types.